# How to mock DocumentClient CreateDocumentQuery AsDocumentQuery

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Only seen two questions on here for this, one wasn't answered and one was an unusable answer (maybe I just didn't get it).  I want to mock this:

```
var eventsFeed = this.documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery(this.collectionUri, 
sqlExpression, feedOptions).AsDocumentQuery();
var events = await eventsFeed.ExecuteNextAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I only seem to be able to get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery to type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.IDocumentQuery

There is a possible answer here:

[Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.IDocumentQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563690/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-linq-enumerablequery-to-type-microsoft-az)

but I can't find the type JTokenEx used in the example and there is no explanation of how to write the mock code?

Ideally I'd like to return some mock results so that I can test the ExecuteNextAsync.

For reference here's the other question I found relating to it but again it wasn't answered:

[How to (should I) mock DocumentClient for DocumentDb unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349659/how-to-should-i-mock-documentclient-for-documentdb-unit-testing)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The `JToken` I know comes from `NewtonSoft.Json`, it's likely that the OP just used that as an example class

Comment: Thanks, I did try it using just JToken but then I didn't know how to construct the class properly and there was no example of that bit.

Comment: The eventsFeed results in a IDocumentQuery<dynamic>, I tried replacing JToken with dynamic but that gives an error "Cannot implement a dynamic interface".

Comment: I answered the previous question. Check to see if that answer applied to your problem as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48432085/5233410